# Rails - Linking two models with has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've already spent weeks on this.
I have two models: User and Classes
The User model can have many Classes
and Classes can have many Users

Here's my Class Model:

```
class Class < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
    belongs_to :users
end
```

And the User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :discipleship_classes
end
```

I can't figure out how to configure the #show method in the User controller to show multiple classes and vice-versa -> show multiple users when viewing Classes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please refer http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2010/09/09/How-to-model-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-rails/, you will find good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

What you've got there is a standard [`has_many/belongs_to`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) relationship:

[image]

Thus, your models should be constructed as so:

```
class DisclipleClass < ActiveRecord::Base
    #columns id | user_id | etc | etc | created_at | updated_at
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :disciple_classes
end
```

Several important notes:

1. If you have an ActiveRecord association in your system, it has to be bi-way -- IE if you have `has_many :classes`, it has to be matched with `belongs_to :class` (unless you do lots of configuration
2. When declaring `belongs_to` associations, you need to keep the association singular. You write it as plural
3. When declaring associations, you can only have one association per name. Your use of `belongs_to :users` and `has_many :users` simply would not be recognized.
4. All associations are basically covers for particular SQL associations. You'd do well to read up on [relational databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database), and how their foreign keys allow them to interact
5. The terms "class, klass" are generally reserved in most languages. Don't use them

---

**has_and_belongs_to_many**

Now, if you wanted to make `many-to-many` relationship, you'd use [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association):

[image]

This will give you the ability to use the following:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :disciple_classes
end

#app/models/disciple_class.rb
class DiscipleClass < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

This will allow you to create a [join table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) as follows:

```
#disciples_classes_users
disciple_class_id | user_id
```

This will allow you to call:

```
@user.disciple_classes
@disciple_class.users
```

Answer (score -1):

In `show` view for `@user`,

```
<% @user.discipleship_classes.each do |d_class|%>
<%= d_class.class.name%>
<%= d_class.some_intrinsic_detail_of_discipleship%>
<% end %>
```